# How to add plugin into laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to add a carousel plugin into laravel.

https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2

so I run **npm install --save owl.carouse** and add following code into **index.blade.php**

```
<script src="/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

The owl.carousel.js is inside my project, but when I run npm run watch, and look at the browser, there show an error in the console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You should not import it through a script tag. Add it in your bootstrap.js file

```
require('owl.carousel');
```

require() will use the node_modules as the root dir

You can of course use require in any other .js file that you then import through a script tag.

If you are using VueJs you do at the top of the vue component

```
import owl from 'owl.carousel'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your web server does not have access to **node_modules** directory.

You'd better use gulp to copy and bundle it to public directory.

Or else if you want, you can do it manually. Copy the script to the **public** directory.
I usually make **asset/js** directory under the **public** and then copy owl under it.

You will have:

```
<script src="/asset/js/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your main .scss file:

```
@import '~owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
```

Compile the css with `npm run dev`

You can repeat these steps for your javascript files

Edit:
If you do not make use of Laravel mix yet, read this documentation first. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix